# z-index not being applied - even though all items have position set

Tags: html, css, z-index

Hi I have some css3 and html5 that shows some text on a notepad with pages behind see http://www.sich.co.uk/test/index.html.

The problem appears to be with the z-index and should be solved by putting in a high z-index no in the article tag however if I do this on the test page it fails. So in the test code as soon as I put a z-index: 2; in article for instance it fails. Take it out and it works perfectly.

In the article tag the z-index:2; is already in simply remove with firebug to see how it should look.

I have been banging my head against a brick wall on this one. Any help would be appreciated. I have included the source html and then the CSS.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Stumped

Paul

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Journal</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patrick+Hand' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<article>
    <h1>Journal Entry #2</h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit.
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit.
    </p>
</article>

<script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>


</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
   width: 540px;
   margin: auto;
   font-family: 'Patrick Hand', sans-serif;
   background: #666;
   color: #666;
}

article {
   margin: 50px auto;
   padding: 20px 50px;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2;               /****** REMOVE THIS z-index to see it working properly *****/ 

   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
   box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
   background: #fcf59b;

   background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#81cbbc), color-stop(2%, #fcf59b));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #81cbbc, #fcf59b 2%);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #81cbbc, #fcf59b 2%);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #81cbbc, #fcf59b 2%);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #81cbbc, #fcf59b 2%);
   background: linear-gradient(top, #81cbbc, #fcf59b 2%);

   -webkit-background-size: 100% 40px;
   -moz-background-size: 100% 40px;
   background-size: 100% 40px;
}


article,article:before,article:after {
   -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px 500px;
   -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 500px 30px;
   -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px 100px;

   -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20 500px;
   -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 500px 30px;
   -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px 100px;


   border-radius-bottomleft: 20 500px;
   border-radius-bottomright: 500px 30px;
   border-radius-topright: 5px 100px;
}

article:after,article:before {
   content: ' ';
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 1;
   position: absolute;
}

article:before {
   background: #fcf6a7;

   -webkit-transform: rotate(4deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(4deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(4deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(4deg);
   transform: rotate(4deg);
}

article:after {
   background: #fcf7b1;

   -webkit-transform: rotate(-4deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(-4deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(-4deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(-4deg);
   transform: rotate(-4deg);
}

p {
   line-height: 2.5em;
   margin-bottom: 40px;
}

h1 {
   padding-top: 8px;
   margin-bottom: -8px;
}
```

Comment: I have tried most of them ie, chrome, firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but if you add `<div style="z-index: 2;">` immediately as a child of `<article contenteditable>`, it may be what you are looking for. (And add the closing `</div>` before `</article>`.)

Comment: Wow thanks a good bit of lateral thinking there. Can't figure out why that should work but it does. Cheers Kevin

Comment: However unfortunately that does not resolve the problem on my homepage where I am using the code [www.sich.co.uk](http://www.sich.co.uk)

Comment: So what I am ultimately trying to achieve is the article:before and the article:after to be at z-index :1; and article to be at z-index:2;. In the test code if I change the article:before and the article:after to z-index:1; then it fails still even with your answer.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you are trying to figure out?

Comment: OK I have updated the code in the question and on the [test site](http://www.sich.co.uk/test/index.html). Now if you change the z-index:1; (in the the article:before, article:after) to z-index: -1; it works. But as the code is now it fails. Thanks for your help Kevin.

Comment: What browser are you testing this in?

Comment: I am testing in multiple browsers inc chrome, safari & firefox. I have now resolved this thanks to a friend of mine.

Answer (score 0):

We resolved this by dropping the pseudo elements and by using the following code.

```
<div class="notepad-container">
     <div class="page1"></div>
     <div class="page2"></div>
     <div class="notepad"></div>
     <h2>Our clients will forget what we said, they will forget what we did, but they will always remember how good we made them feel.</h2>
</div>
```

and the following css

```
/***********************************************
* Create notepad style box for our text
************************************************/

.notepad-container {
   width: 550px;
   margin: auto;
   margin-bottom:30px;
   margin-top:15px;
   height: 200px;
   position:relative;
   z-index: 0;

}



.notepad, .page1, .page2 {
   width: 550px;
   height:200px;
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;

   -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px 500px;
   -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 500px 30px;
   -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px 100px;

   -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20 500px;
   -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 500px 30px;
   -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px 100px;

   border-radius-bottomleft: 20 500px;
   border-radius-bottomright: 500px 30px;
   border-radius-topright: 5px 100px;


}
.notepad {
   background: #fcf59b;


   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
   box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.15);

   background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#81cbbc), color-stop(2%, #fcf59b));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #81cbbc, #fcf59b 2%);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #81cbbc, #fcf59b 2%);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #81cbbc, #fcf59b 2%);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #81cbbc, #fcf59b 2%);
   background: linear-gradient(top, #81cbbc, #fcf59b 2%);

   -webkit-background-size: 100% 40px;
   -moz-background-size: 100% 40px;
   background-size: 100% 40px;
}


.page1 {
   background: #fcf6a7;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;

   -webkit-transform: rotate(4deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(4deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(4deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(4deg);
   transform: rotate(4deg);
   position: absolute;
   z-index: -1;
}

.page2 {
   background: #fcf7b1;


   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-4deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(-4deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(-4deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(-4deg);
   transform: rotate(-4deg);
   position: absolute;
   z-index: -1;
}


.notepad-container h2 {
   font-family: 'bad script', sans-serif;
   line-height: 1.7em!important;
   margin-bottom: 40px;
   margin-top: 0px;
   font-style:italic;
   position: absolute;
   margin: 0px auto;
   padding: 10px 50px;

   z-index: 2;
   width: 450px;
   height: 250px;
   top:0;
   left:0;

}
```

See my WordPress [homepage](http://www.sich.co.uk) for it in action.